# Different actual font size on the page when displayed on desktop browsers on Windows and mobile on Android

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem when trying to increase the font on the mobile version of the site. The font size in the CSS is indicated in px, but visually, by the number of words that fit in a line on the same page, when viewed in the browser chrome and firefox, the desktop version of windows and android differ, on android the font is actually smaller - i.e. more words will fit in a line.
[image: Screenshot_win-ff][image: Screenshot_android-ff]

What is the reason? And how to fix it?

I tried changing px to pt, same result.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: please provide an example of code, or link to code, or anything else.
Possible reasons may be: unset viewport, font that exist in window only, css styles that works differently etc.

Comment: p, table, input, select{font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana;}

Comment: meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, user-scalable=yes" id="viewport-meta"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the font, I replaced it with another and managed to achieve almost complete identity.